# How to clean out node / npm snd start again. node-gyp error

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I've been trying to get node-gyp going on a windows machine for many days now on and off. I'm quite stuck , I can't even run npm install ( anything ) , I can't install or uninstall node-gyp .

I have followed instructions online ( from a while ago ) to delete the node-gyp directory.  I have removed node completely , removed anything node in %appdata% subsirectories , but the error still appears after rebooting etc. I have tried updating npm to the latest version.

Every time I get this message;

```
MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp'
```

I can't get my head around what is going on here.  I would have thought that reinstalling node would have fixed things.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: trying install node completely again

Comment: Thanks for your comment @owaishanif786 if you read the post , you can see that is one of the things I have done ( a few times actually )

Comment: Can you use your terminal at all?

Comment: yes @rags2riches . It's a relatively new windows install

Comment: OK, if you are on windows, can you enter `where node-gyp` and see if you get a path back in the command line? Can you also share the exact command you enter that lead to the error?